# Assistance needed with Power BI via Group By

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In my Power BI report, I am reporting on the `DefectID` to give my end users a report if a defect happened and it's corresponding count which will end up being be a non-zero number. Sometimes, there are no defects and will return 0.

I am grouping my data within the Power Query Editor and my groupings are as follows:

`Table.Group(vw_GainseekerData_DMS_By_Defect_Type_, {"SAMPLEDATE", "PARTNO", "LINE_NUMBER", "SIGNON_ID", "CAVITY", "SSIZE", "DefectID"}, {{"MinDefectCount", each List.Min([DefectCount]), type nullable number}}`)

If a defect occurs, I will get the corresponding ID and a zero - which, my SQL Server table is from a third party vendor and is field based (20 DefectIDs and 20 DefectCounts) which I have UNPIVOTED to be come row based. I cannot change the table structure.

I feel like I am ALMOZSZT there as I can see the data but, if I have a defect, I will also get a zero, likely because I am grouping by the Defect ID but I can't see a way around that.

My data looks like the screen capture below. I want the zero to be gone unless it's grouping has no defect ID.

[image]